# How to dynamically add Predicate into List

Tags: java, list, java-8, predicate

Is there any way to dynamically add Predicate into List in Java? For a brief illustration I've done it like this:

```
List<Predicate<String>> filters = Arrays.asList(
    t -> !Utilities.isNumeric(t)
);
filters.add(t -> !t.isEmpty());
```

But executing the `filters.add` results in UnsupportedOperationException. Fixed List like this is fine tho.

```
List<Predicate<String>> filters = Arrays.asList(
    t -> !Utilities.isNumeric(t),
    t -> !t.isEmpty()
);
```

Comment: is that because you need to apply both `Predicate`s to some input?

Comment: Yes. Actually I want to combine them later. The implementation is much complex than that. It is used in a class which is used in other classes, and different calling class will have its own set of filters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

```
List<Predicate<String>> filters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    t -> !Utilities.isNumeric(t)
));
```

Explanation:

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-length list<sup>1</sup> wrapper for the array argument.  Since it is fixed sized, methods that would change the size throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

By feeding this to the `ArrayList` constructor, you create a new list, whose size can be changed.

---

<sup>1 - .... but the list is **NOT immutable**.  It can be modified by updating the backing array, or by using the `List::set(int, T)` method.</sup>

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you so much, it's working now.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) creates a fixed size list: you cannot add to a list obtained with this method.

You have to create a mutable List, for instance by using `new ArrayList()`:

```
List<Predicate<String>> filters = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
  t -> !Utilities.isNumeric(t)
));
filters.add(t -> !t.isEmpty());
```

will work, since the `filters`list is mutable.

Answer (score 2):

[Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) returns an **fixed** instance of a List:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

It is rather meant as "shortcut" when you "manually" write down a list of things. A "fixed size" list of things to be precise. This means you can "replace" elements, but not add or remove entries.

So simply use the result of that call as input for creating another list, like: `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need *both* `Predicate`s applied to some input, you can chain them. The only downside that there is a lot of casting involved - since lambda expressions and method references are poly expressions...

```
Predicate<String> both = ((Predicate<String>) Utilities::isNumeric).negate()
                             .and(((Predicate<String>) String::isEmpty).negate());
```

Comment: I'm still learning java 8, nice info btw. Yeah, actually in the end, I want to combine all filters, and I use this `compositeFilter = filters.stream().reduce(f -> true, Predicate::and)`